# callback within b2contactlistener begincontact

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a contact listener to detect collisions between a bullet and an asteroid. Inside the beginContact function i check for the sprite types and fire a block from within this function.

The block is set by the scene class when it is allocated, before the contact listener is assigned to the box2dworld. The bullets and asteroids both get box2d bodies as well as sprites.

The problem is that i can access the sprites and do whatever i want with them (run actions, stop actions etc.).

However, as soon as i call the removeChild function on the sprite, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the b2Contact::Update on listener->BeginContact(this).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My tick function:

```
//Physics simulation
_world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();

        b2Vec2 b2Position = b2Vec2(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO,
                                   sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
        float32 b2Angle = -1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(sprite.rotation);

        b->SetTransform(b2Position, b2Angle);
    }
}

for(CCSprite *sprite in spritesToDelete) {
    [self removeSprite:sprite];
    [spritesToDelete removeObject:sprite];
    sprite = nil;
}
```

My contact listener callback block:

```
 contactListener->contactBlock = ^(CCSprite *A, CCSprite *B) {

        NSLog(@"A: %@", [A class]);
        NSLog(@"B: %@", [B class]);
        CCSprite *bullet = nil , *asteroid = nil;
        if ([(NSString *)A.userData isEqualToString:@"asteroid"] && [(NSString *)B.userData isEqualToString:@"bullet"])
        {
            asteroid = A;
            bullet = B;
        } else if ([(NSString *)B.userData isEqualToString:@"asteroid"] && [(NSString *)A.userData isEqualToString:@"bullet"])
        {
            asteroid = B;
            bullet = A;
        }

        if (asteroid != nil && bullet != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Asteroid Hit!");
            [asteroid stopAllActions];
            [bullet stopAllActions];
            //If I keep the line below uncommented, I get the error. Adding actions and stuff does not make an issue, only removal of sprite is when I get the error.
            [spritesToDelete addObject:bullet];
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put a pointer to your sprite in `b2UserData` of `b2Body` or `b2Fixure` in order to retrieve when collision happens. When you delete the sprite, this pointer will point to a deleted instance and thus you receive `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

You should nullify the pointer to eliminate the problem

Comment: In my removeSprite function, I iterate through the b2world bodies for the sprite's body. I remove the b2body first, and then remove the sprite. You look like pretty close to the issue because I get the error from b2contact::Update which is called through the b2world->step function. Any ideas where I might be wrong? I do nullify the pointer as the removeSprite function finishes.

Comment: @user2504181: You can't remove bodies while inside `b2World::step` functions. You have to store the data required to remove the body somewhere, and actually remove it only when `step` exits

Comment: I did it in my `tick` function, after the `b2world->step` function. I still get the error. I'm going crazy on this one, since this is my first time with Box2D, it's a bit difficult for me to wrap my head around it. Thanks for your patience though :)

Comment: Any more insight into the matter, if you have the time to spare?

Comment: @ABHashmi: can you please post some code, otherwise its hard to say anything

Comment: My `tick` function:
    _world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            b2Vec2 b2Position = b2Vec2(sprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, sprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
            float32 b2Angle = -1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(sprite.rotation);
            b->SetTransform(b2Position, b2Angle);
 } }
    for(CCSprite *sprite in spritesToDelete) {
        [self removeSprite:sprite];
        [spritesToDelete removeObject:sprite];
        sprite = nil;
    }

Comment: @ABHashmi: do not delete sprite from spritesToDelete while iterating. Use `[spritesToDelete removeAllObjects]` after the cycle

Comment: Sorry, got this error, still exc_bad_access:

    `thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x43200000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x43200000)
    frame #0: 0x43200000
    frame #1: 0x000ed13b` `Asteroids`b2Contact::Update(this=0x0ac46e80, listener=0x139922b0) + 907 at b2Contact.cpp:228`

Comment: For reference, this is my `ContactListener::BeginContact` <br />

`CCSprite * spriteA = (CCSprite *)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();`
`CCSprite * spriteB = (CCSprite *)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();`
`contactBlock(spriteA, spriteB);`
where contactBlock is provided by the scene class

Comment: I think I found it! While I was stepping into the block with no access to the deletion array, I noticed that the pointer to the array was nil. Also, the pointer to `self` was nil, too. I'm a bit new to blocks so I don't know what to do here. Any help would be much appreciated.